# find document in today's date range in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection, `Plans`. I want to find everything within the range of one month. Here is a sample of what the data could look like:

```
{
  "_id": "someid",
  "dateStart": ISODate("2015-03-01T00:00:00Z"),
  "dateEnd": ISODate("2015-03-31T00:00:00Z"),
  "items": [
    "someotherid"
  ]
}
```

How can I find the `Plan` such that today's date is between `dateStart` and `dateEnd`?

Answer (score 2):

```js
date1 = new Date('3/1/15');
date2 = new Date('4/1/15');

Plans.find({
  startDate: {$gte: date1},
  endDate: {$lt: date2}
});
```

New `Date` objects initialize to `00:00:000` so you can use that to your advantage here. Also note that "less than 4/1" is equivalent to "less than or equal to midnight on 3/31" - but the former is much easier to write.

Also note that [moment](http://momentjs.com/) is a super handy utility for doing manipulations like this. For example: `moment().endOf('month').toDate()`

To add the package just do:

`$ meteor add momentjs:moment`

Answer (score 2):

To find a Plan such that today's date is between the `dateStart` and `dateEnd` fields, create a date object that holds the current date then use the `$lt` and `$gt` query operators on the date fields to query documents where today's date falls between the two fields:

```
currentDate = new Date();
Plans.find({
    dateStart: { $lt: currentDate },
    dateEnd: { $gt: currentDate }
});
```