# Select the parameters MongoDB MeteorJS

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to return `posts` that created today and sort them by date `{ sort: { createdAt: -1 }}`

**Code I Have :**

```
<template name="m_table_time">
  <div class="container">
        <h1 class="table_date">Today</h1>
        {{> m_table posts=today}}
  </div>
</template>

Template.m_table_time.helpers({
  today: function() {
    var today = moment().toDate();
    var daystart  = moment().startOf('day').toDate();
    return Posts.find({},{ sort: { createdAt: -1 }},{$gte: daystart, $lte: today  }); // this doesnt work
  },

<template name="m_table">
          <table class="main-table table">
              {{#each posts}}
                {{> m_jobs}}
              {{/each}}
          </table>
</template>
```

Also I tried to do something like this

```
return Posts.find({},{ sort: { createdAt: -1 }},{bigpost:true}); // also this doesnt work
```

Anybody help ?

Comment: Are your dates `Date` BSON types or are they actually "strings"? Not to mention. "What are you doing?". You specifiy a query with `$gte` etc in the "query". Where did you ever think there is a third argument to `.find()` like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to [find](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) is the selector, and that's where your date rules need to go:

```js
var selector = {createdAt: {$gte: daystart, $lte: today}};
return Posts.find(selector, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237982/find-document-in-todays-date-range-in-mongodb).

Answer (score 0):

Your find method should be structured like so:

```
Posts.find(
 { createdAt: {$gte: daystart, $lte: today} },
 { sort : {createdAt: -1} }
);
```